# Buildozer assembling error: buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/gradlew failed

Tags: firebase, ubuntu, gradle, kivy, buildozer

I have tried to build an android app using buildozer on Ubuntu x86_64. All went well till the following error:

```
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'aab', '--bootstrap', 'sdl2', '--dist_name', 'Epidemy', '--name', 'Epidemy', '--version', '0.2.2.13', '--package', 'com.legeartisgames.epidemy', '--minsdk', '22', '--ndk-api', '22', '--private', '/home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/app', '--permission', 'INTERNET', '--permission', 'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE', '--permission', 'VIBRATE', '--permission', 'com.android.vending.BILLING', ...
```

To be precise it is not the first place where the process failed:

```
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 34.0.0
[DEBUG]:   -> running dos2unix /home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/gradlew
[DEBUG]:    dos2unix: converting file /home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/gradlew to Unix format...
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew clean bundleRelease
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Where:
[DEBUG]:    Build file '/home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/build.gradle' line: 80
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Could not compile build file '/home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/build.gradle'.
[DEBUG]:    > startup failed:
[DEBUG]:      build file '/home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/build.gradle': 80: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 80, column 14.
[DEBUG]:         dependencies {
[DEBUG]:                      ^
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:      1 error
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 391ms
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
Exception in thread background thread for pid 283400:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/alex/Epidemy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/Epidemy/gradlew clean bundleRelease

  STDOUT:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I am absolutely at a loss about the case. Indeed the original code in build.gradle that caused the failure was not in the least different in syntax from upper parts:

```
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

}

dependencies {  # critical line
    implementation ''com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0''
....
}
```

Upon further experiments I commented the line containing firebase in buildozer.spec and it worked and produced aab file!

I am not a maven either at buildozer or firebase specifics, so I will be grateful to anyone who shares some information on it.

Upd: I checked "blank" buildozer file, that one might get from "buildozer init", and found out that no firebase exists here. I ran the old buildozer file that I copied from another computer and that was used quite a long ago, so it is most probable that Google has changes its firebase version requirements as with NDK up to 25b and it caused the error. But I still do not understand the actual reason of failure.